# Why does the IsPressedChanged event not work with an interaction trigger but other events do?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Edit:** To make it short: as AFigmentOfMyImagination pointed out in his answer, there exists no `IsPressedChanged` event. However, here is the original question:

I have a button and I want a command to be executed both when the button is pressed and when it is released. The standard command binding of buttons can only call the command either when the button is pressed OR released so I figured I might achieve what I want using an interaction trigger on the `IsPressedChanged` event like so:

```xml
<Button xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="IsPressedChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

But this does not work. It does however work when I use other events like the `MouseEnter` event.

Now my question is, why is that? What is the difference between the `IsPressedChanged` event and other events? It seems to me as if there is some conceptual difference and I'd like to know what that is (and maybe why there needs to be a difference).

**Edit:** I have found a way to have the command beeing executed on every `IsPressed` change. That solution is used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72230510/15432738).

Comment: I think you want to use `OnIsPressedChanged` instead `IsPressedChanged`

Comment: There is no such event named "IsPressedChanged". There is a dependency property "IsPressed" whose changes you could observe / react on.

Comment: @Felix: Can't you handle the `MouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseLeftButtonUp` events?

Comment: @mm8: Yes, but these would not work with pointing devices other than a mouse.

Comment: @mm8: Thats correct. My question was WHY it did not work and AFigmentOfMyImagination did perfectly answer that. (I have already figured out how to hadle the event using a custom button implementation and a routed CustomIsPressedChanged event. Which i will post another question on concearning another propblem once I am allowed to.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `IsPressedChanged` and `MouseEvent` is that `MouseEvent` is an event provided by `Button` whereas `IsPressedChanged` is not.

Put differently, something that does not exist cannot really "work"...

Comment: Hum, that was to easy. Thx for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

[EventTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.eventtrigger?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) are used for routed event.
There is no `IsPressedChanged` routed event, the only routed event provided by a `Button` is [Click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and it doesn't match your needs.
In [*global* routed events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24165711/361177), you can find `Mouse.MouseDown` and `Mouse.MouseUp` but you will miss the cases where the button is pressed via the keyboard.

You can use the `Button.IsPressed` property via data trigger and by setting the binding source to be the button (by using [ElementName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.elementname) or [RelativeSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource)).
But you will have to [bodge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIFE7h3m40U) it a little so it trig either if the value is `true` or `false`.
Luckily, neither `true` or `false` are equal to the empty string. By setting `DataTrigger.Comparison` to `"NotEqual"` and `Value` to `""` you ensure that the trigger is triggered each time `IsPressed` changed.
(A possible undesired effect: it trig as soon as the control is created.)

```xml
<Button x:Name="Button">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>

<!--
        You can also use this binding
        <i:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button},  
                                         Path=IsPressed}"
-->

        <i:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button, Path=IsPressed}"
                       Comparison="NotEqual"
                       Value="">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=PressedChangedCommand}"/>
        </i:DataTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Working demo available [here](https://github.com/Orace/SO/tree/main/SO_72229375).

Comment: You can remove the `Value=""` line since `unset` is neither equals to `True` or `False` too. But you may loose in clarity.

Comment: Wow, this is a great solution. This is way more compact than creating a custom button which fires a new routed event from the OnIsPressedChanged method. Thank you very much!